# "Test Item" and "Test Condition" in Software testing

Tags: testing, function-points

In writing Test case as I know, first step/task is to identify the Test Item/Function point and Test Condition. What is "Test Item" and "Test Condition" and what's the process/way to identify them? Please explain with an example.

Comment: This should not have been downvoted. The ISTQB syllabus and other testing standards, flowing from IEEE I suppose, tend to use a few terms with definitions that seem arbitrary. It's good to know where the definition of these jargon terms come from because they are not very meaningful in English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Test item: The individual element to be tested. There are basically many test items in a "test object" which actually is a component/subsystem to be tested. No need to quote an example here since it is quite self-explanatory.

2) Test condition: An item or event of a component or system that could be verified by one or more test cases, e.g. a function, transaction, feature, quality attribute, or structural element. For example, for a `username` field on a signup form, test conditions could be like 
       - It shouldn't start with a non-alphabet 
       - It can contain utmost two digits with no non-alphanumeric characters after the first input character.

Answer (score 2):

Test condition is the condition which is the Process that you should follow to test an application.

Ex: – You Have Login Form.
Test Condition 1:- when User Name and Password are valid 
Then application will move forward.
The above one is the test condition which is the basic Condition where that tests process will get pass.

Test Item : test item indicates what are all the items need to test in software application and what need to no test ...

Example :
Suppose we are starting to test eCommerce site, initially we need to test items which are required (i.e)
1.We need to validate customer registration form
2.Check out process is main item

Comment: Can you please give example of Test Item?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of an IEEE 829 test plan, "test item" refers to the code package that is being tested. According to the textbook, *Software Testing: An ISTQB-ISEB Foundation Guide*, "a test item is a software item that is the object of testing . A software item is one or more items of source code, object code, job control code, or control data".

Comment: This quote proves that the language is arbitrary. "an item that is the object"  and "item is one or more items". Item, Element, Object, all could be interpreted to mean "thing". This is great fun. It's a hall of mirrors, but we need to know what the Professor says it is so we can pass the test! In fact, the thing being tested is not always a SOFTWARE item, it can be part of a design document; IEEE should hire a rhetorical philosopher to clear this up.

Answer (score 0):

Test Item: The individual element to be tested. There usually is one test object and many test items.

Test Condition: An item or event of a component or system that could be verified by one or more test cases, e.g., a function, transaction, feature, quality attribute or structural element.

For example:
Test Object: Login form

Test Item: Login authentication

Test Condition: 1) both username and password are blank
2) username is blank, password is invalid
..... and so on

Is it helpful?

Comment: `There usually is one test object ` Why? A full-fledged application can have many components/sub-systems.

Comment: yes, a full-fledged application can have many components/subsystems -- it's right. I didn't mean that. My explanation is: one object might contain many test items, e.g., Login component has many test items. Login is one of the components of an application, this application has other test object/components also

Comment: Component can be Test Object or a System can be Test Object. One Test Object can have many Test Items.

Answer (score -2):

**Case1** : First take it as "username and password " with valid data..

**Case2** : Username and Password should be accept the min 6-8 characters

**Case3** : Username field should accept the "Alphanumerics" and password should accept the alphanumerics and special symbols also.

**Case4** : Username and password should not be accept the empty values.

**Case5**: Take it the user name as valid and Password field as Empty.it should be display the Validation.

**Case6** : Take it the User Name as Empty and Password field as valid data.it should be display the validation.

**Case7** : username and password fields both are invalid like min-1 characters.it should not be accepted.

**Case 8**: User Name and Password Fields both accept invalid details like Max+1 characters.it should not accepted.

**Case 9**: password should be accept the min+mid/2 characters.

**Case 10** : Username and password fields should be accept the valid data like min+1 and Max-1 characters.